# For what real values is the following function discontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $x$ is irrational or $x=0$, we set $f(x)=0$. If $x \in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x=m/n$ such that

1. $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$,
2. $GCF(m,n)=1$,

then we set $f(x)=1/n$.

I find this question confusing because of its resemblance to the well-known function $g$ where if $x$ is irrational then $g(x)=0$ and if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $g(x)=1$, which is discontinuous everywhere.

In that case, the fact that there are irrational and rational numbers arbitrarily close to any real number $a$ prevents $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ from existing; and it isn't clear to me why the same fact doesn't prevent the limit from existing in this case.

Comment: Given $a\in\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$, note/show that there are only finitely many $x=m/n$ with $|a-x|<1$ and $1/n>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to any irrational number, the ones that are close have large denominators so the function value will be small.  We can imagine an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.  To be specific, imagine we are proving continuity at $\pi$.  $f(\pi)=0$.  Now suppose somebody gives us an $\epsilon \gt 0$ and asks what $\delta$ will ensure $f(x) \lt \epsilon$ as long as $|x-\pi| \lt \delta$.  We need the denominator of all the rationals in $(\pi - \delta,\pi+\delta)$ to be greater than $\frac 1\epsilon$.  We can just take each denominator up to $\frac 1\epsilon$, find the closest fraction with that denominator, see how far it is from $\pi$, take the minimum of the list, and set $\delta$ less than that.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful example, I will try the ϵ−δ proof.